# Who command in windows

Tags: windows, security, unix, command-line

Is there any equivalent of `who` command in Windows? How can I view all the logged in users and sessions in the CMD terminal or powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PS C:\> quser
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>jeffrey rennie        console             1  Active      none   4/20/2017 2:40 PM
PS C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie> quser -h
Invalid parameter(s)
Display information about users logged on to the system.

QUERY USER [username | sessionname | sessionid] [/SERVER:servername]

  username            Identifies the username.
  sessionname         Identifies the session named sessionname.
  sessionid           Identifies the session with ID sessionid.
  /SERVER:servername  The server to be queried (default is current).

PS C:\>
```

Comment: Awesome, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Windows don't have command equivalent to "WHO" command of linux, but you can use below commands.

use quser to check active settions.

for users check you can use command "net user"

and to check active remote sessions you can use command "netstat". check port 3389 if active. 3389 is use for RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol). it will not tell you the users but will show you the ip list active on port 3389 (remote users).

Answer (score 1):

You may use this "rwhod for Windows"
https://rwhod-win.sourceforge.net

Unlike rwhod on Unix, this version doesn't store whod information for other clients on the network. You'll need a Unix computer also running rwhod with the ruptime and rwho clients for this program to be useful.